# LEFT JOIN 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables I want to join, so far I have a `LEFT JOIN` which works OK but I would like it to be more specific.

As it is now:

```
SELECT m.fname, m.lname, m.position, COUNT(d.mId) AS shifts 
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN duty_sched AS d
ON d.mId = m.id AND month(d.shift_date) = $month
WHERE m.active_mbr = '1' AND m.fname != 'memorial'
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY m.lname, m.fname
```

Inside d I have a column named `status`, I want to also have that in the mix. The list must contain ALL the people from members with a shift count in `duty_sched`.

Example:

```
Name (Count)

John  (1)
Mary  (0)
Mark  (2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying all the wonderful answers I found that is I added the filter to the ON line it works like I wanted. You are all great and have given me awesome ways to do things. Being a beginner I find this forums to be very informative and most times fix the problems I'm having. Thanks ya'll!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT m.fname, m.lname, m.position, COUNT(d.mId) AS shifts FROM
members as m
LEFT JOIN duty_sched AS d
ON d.mId = m.id AND month(d.shift_date) = $month
WHERE m.active_mbr = '1' AND m.fname != 'memorial'
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING COUNT(d.mId)>0
ORDER BY m.lname, m.fname
```

Comment: Tried this and if the count = 0 the name does not appear. Only those with an assigned shift shows in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are filtering out members in the `where` clause.  To get all such members, move the condition into the `select` as a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT m.fname, m.lname, m.position,
       sum(case when m.active_mbr = '1' AND m.fname != 'memorial' then 1 else 0 end) AS shifts 
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN duty_sched AS d
ON d.mId = m.id AND month(d.shift_date) = $month
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY m.lname, m.fname
```

The `sum(case . . .)` is very similar to the `count()` except it is processing all the rows, even rows that failed your original `where` conditions.  However, those rows get a value of `0`.